# Magento Cache - confusion about Varnish, Redis, APC, Memcache

Tags: magento, redis, memcached, varnish, apc

I'm try to improve Magento performances ( soon or later "MageDev" hit this point :)

I did some research and I found a lot of good, but not homogeneous, guides.

What I got is that:

- *MemCache* or *Redis* are generic cache system, they cache data and they can be integrated directly with Magento (*local.xml*)
- *APC* is a cache for the php code itself can only be integrated at server level.
- *Varnish* is a reverse proxy, it cache the response can only be integrated at server level. ( there is a extension for Magento, turpentine,  but I'm not sure what exactly does )

After all this good reading I'm still a bit confused about what of the above cache systems is possible to use in combinations, for EX:

- MemCache + APC ?
- Redis + APC  ?
- can I add Varnish to one of the above configuration ?

Just to be clear the question is not about how to configure Magento or the server but what 
are the possibility allowed and some clearance about how to mix cache systems. ( beside that if anyone can come with a good recommendation I would appreciate it thanks. )

Answer (score 0):

All these are different things, so they don't depend on each other.
APC caches the compiled code, MemCache stores data in memory and Redis is a persistent storage for different data structures.
Question is not clear, because you didn't point where is the bottleneck of your project

Comment: The question is about the confusion I have on those kind of cache ... it is difficult to say where is the bottleneck, Magento is a complex and heavy project it self, then there is mysql and apache behind it ... plus the code of third party ext ...

Comment: On my side I have profiled the code a removed all code bottle neck, I also found some Magento code that was slow so I have fixed it but you can do miracle at the end the code execution consume CPU cycle so you need to relay on some workaround to save CPU ( also that has a price and usually is paid with Ram )

Comment: So, if your project is a classic web-site with SQL-based DB, you can use APC and MemCache for caching quering results. It's a common practice. Redis is more specific thing.

Comment: it is not a "classic" site it is Magento site.
Magento is a platform based on Zend Framework and gives you the possibility to interface its internal cache system with different cache backend (APC/Redis/Memcache/DB/Filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit tricky and I also posted the same question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48003/magento-cache-confusion-about-varnish-redis-apc-memcache

I got an very good answer from @sonassi.

If the double question is a against Stack policy let me know and I will close this one.